# Chrome: Images don't show up

Tags: bug

Is it just me or is this a bug?
This morning I realized uploaded images don't show up in Chrome (64.0.3282.119), while displaying correctly in Firefox.

Chrome:
[image]

Firefox:
[image]

Comment: Someone just asked this on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48512347/2564301. As I hadn't yet upgraded, I was able to replicate this pre- and post-update.

Comment: I second @usr2564301's observation: #63 shows no problems, but #64 only shows half the button on the SO page. Image on GDSE page is good, though.